# I need to perform add, delete, update, read data using xml. this code has probs?

Tags: c#, xml

```
    private const string filename = "output.xml";

    /// <summary>
    /// Create file code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextWriter newXmlFile = new XmlTextWriter(filename,System.Text.Encoding.Default);    
        newXmlFile.WriteStartDocument();            
        newXmlFile.WriteStartElement("Begin","");
        newXmlFile.WriteStartElement("One","");
        newXmlFile.WriteFullEndElement();
        newXmlFile.WriteEndElement();
        newXmlFile.Flush();
        newXmlFile.Close();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert New code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       XmlDocument XMLDom = new XmlDocument();
        XMLDom.Load(filename);
        XmlNode newXMLNode = XMLDom.SelectSingleNode("Begin");
        XmlNode childNode = XMLDom.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"One","");
        XmlAttribute newAttribute = XMLDom.CreateAttribute("name","sree","");
        childNode.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);
        newXMLNode.AppendChild(childNode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @Abdel Olakara - you are making an assumption. Could also be a noob who needs a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and the [`System.Xml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Like Oded says: Linq to XML should get you there...

These classes are the important ones:

- `XDocument`

  - `var doc = XDocument.Load("myfilepath")
- `XElement`
- `XAttribute`